# Mathematica find values from function in particular points

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, there is this function:
`F(x)=a*sin(1*x/b)+b*cos(1*x/c) + d`

How to find values of this function in particular points from `Xi=-2,-1.8,-1.6,...2` ?

So in the end it will be like `-2 = ...., -1.8 = .....,` etc..

I guess some graphic needs to be used here so I can see those values from it? Or any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I got it:

`Table[{a*Sin[(1*x)/b] + b*Cos[(1*x)/c] // N}, {x, -2, 2, 0.2}]`

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question.  Better to do that than put the answer in a comment.